# Does the Rails Console reload initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using the Rails Console to test a few things by hand and found that one of my initializers (under config/initializers) had an error. I exited the console, made the change, and ran "rails c" again. Much to my surprise, the updated initializer was not executed.

Here is what I found:

-- If I start a new Bash session and enter "rails c" all the initializers get executed.

-- If I add / change an initializer and then re-run "rails c" within the same Bash session, the initializers are not executed.

This occurs under development which disables caching.

What the heck is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is what I expect. Hence my question. :)

Comment: Have you tried restarting spring?

Comment: Uh, "spring"? I have no idea to what you are referring. This is a simple, Ruby on Rails console.

Comment: Which specific version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Spring: https://github.com/rails/spring

Comment: Try running `$ spring stop` after closing and before starting your rails console.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the marked question. This is about Rails 4.1 + - the marked dupe is Rails 3. The answer may be to run 'reload!' but that is not the best answer, and the reason why reload helps is different.

Answer (score 22):

The introduction of [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) was meant to make loading your rails app faster, by keeping a copy of the app in memory and only reloading what changes.

Unfortunately, sometimes your initializers can stay exactly the same, but they need to be re-run. An example is the "business_time" gem, which generates an initializer that loads a YAML file. You can change the YAML file and restart console, but Spring sees that your initializer hasn't changed, so it doesn't re-run it. Thus, the changes to your YAML file go unnoticed, This is a very difficult error to troubleshoot.

If you're having initializer problems, then exit out of console and run:

```
bundle exec spring stop
```

before going back into console. This will force a fresh reload of the initializers.

You can also disable Spring entirely by removing the gem from your Gemfile.

Comment: Can't believe this, wasted 1.5 hours trying to figure out why ENV vars were showing as `nil` in initializers until a colleague pointed me to this.

Comment: I added `at_exit { `spring stop` }` to solve this issue

Answer (score -3):

Type this command into rails

```
reload!
```

It's reload your rails c

Comment: Be careful, not initializers ;)